# While adding the maven dependency in bazel project,unable to running the bazel run @maven//:pin,getting maven_install.json as empty.facing below issue

Tags: bazel, bazel-extra-action, bazel-java

bazel run @maven//:pin
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
INFO: Analyzed target @maven//:pin (7 packages loaded, 26 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target @maven//:pin up-to-date:
bazel-bin/external/maven/pin
bazel-bin/external/maven/pin.exe
INFO: Elapsed time: 14.964s, Critical Path: 0.13s
INFO: 1 process: 1 internal.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
INFO: Build completed successfully, 1 total action
Starting local Bazel server and connecting to it...
C:\Users\mohit.jaiswal_bazel_mohit.jaiswal\3crxb23l\execroot_*main*_\bazel-out\x64_windows-fastbuild\bin\external\maven\pin: line 13: ../maven/jq: No such file o
r directory

---

and maven_install.json file is showing empty

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure github.com/bazelbuild/rules_jvm_external is added properly in the worksapce file. Clean the build by [bazel clean --expunge] and try compiling it again.